# js. Поиск элементов по name

Tags: javascript

Есть обычная html форма, типа

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="sum" value="22"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="age" value="18"> 
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Получим форму в js, `var form = document.querySelector('#form');`.

Вопрос, как получить элемент этой формы с именем `sum`, `form.getElementsByName('sum')[0];` не работает, т.к. `getElementsByName` применяется только к `document`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
// Длинно и нудно
console.log(document.getElementById('form').querySelector('[name="sum"]'))

// Короче, но всё ещё длинно и нудно
console.log(document.querySelector('#form input[name="sum"]'))

// Коротко
console.log(form.elements.sum)

// Ещё короче
console.log(form.sum)
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
  <input type="hidden" name="sum" value="22">
  <input type="hidden" name="age" value="18">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне понравился этот вариант `document.querySelector('#form input[name="sum"]')`, все таки querySelector мощная штука.

Comment: А мне `form.sum` тем что коротко записывается и легко читается

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте

Такое должно сработать:

```
var form = document.querySelector('#form');
var sum= form.elements.sum.value; // значение sum
```